# GoToWebinar organizer Key

Tags: web-services, citrix

How do you obtain the organizer key used in the GoToWebinar REST API? There does not seem to be any help on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://developer.citrixonline.com/forum/trying-get-oauth) url from citrix's developer blog illustrates the procedure.

Comment: It's part of the response in the auth flow. https://developer.citrixonline.com/page/authentication-and-authorization

Comment: These links are dead. It would be useful if you could provide more information.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be in the response anymore from the auth flow. Annoying. The only advice I've seen is to find the organizer key in the URL while viewing the billing page. This can't be the only way to find this info.